# Set secret variable when using Docker in TravisCI

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I build a backend with NodeJS and would like to use TravisCI and Docker to run tests.

In my code, I have a secret env: process.env.SOME_API_KEY

This is my Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

My docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
    - /app/node_modules
    - .:/app
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.6
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

And this is my TravisCI

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_script:
  - docker-compose up -d --build

script:
  - docker-compose exec api npm run test
```

I also set SOME_API_KEY='xxx' in my travis setting variables. However, it seems that the container doesn't receive the SOME_API_KEY.

How can I pass the SOME_API_KEY from travisCI to docker? Thanks

Comment: please make sure to add the environment variables in Travis ( settings page ) within quotation mark eg:  `FOO="foo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers in general do not inherit the environment from which they are run.  Consider something like this:

```
export SOMEVARIABLE=somevalue
docker run --rm alpine sh -c 'echo $SOMEVARIABLE'
```

That will never print out the value of `$SOMEVARIABLE` because there is no magic process to import environment variables from your local shell into the container. If you want a travis environment variable exposed inside your docker containers, you will need to do that explicitly by creating an appropriate `environment` block in your `docker-compose.yml`. For example, I use the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  example:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c 'echo $SOMEVARIABLE'
    environment:
      SOMEVARIABLE: "${SOMEVARIABLE}"
```

I can then run the following:

```
export SOMEVARIABLE=somevalue
docker-compose up
```

And see the following output:

```
Recreating docker_example_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_example_1
example_1  | somevalue
docker_example_1 exited with code 0
```

So you will need to write something like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      SOME_API_KEY: "${SOME_API_KEY}"

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.6
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: and the value of SOME_API_KEY comes from Travis variable settings?

Comment: Assuming you have configured that, yes.  You could stick a command in your script prior to running `docker-compose` to verify that the variable is in the environment (e.g., `awk 'BEGIN{for(v in ENVIRON) print v}'`, which prints environment variables *names* without printing values).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and solve it passing the environment variable to the container in `docker-compose exec` command. If the variable is in the Travis environment, you can do:

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_script:
  - docker-compose up -d --build

script:
  - docker-compose exec -e SOME_API_KEY=$SOME_API_KEY api npm run test
```